# paper (tape) showing after sanding

Tags: drywall, mudding, taping

After some initial sanding of a taped joint, the tape/paper is showing. It's sticking out and frayed, and still needs some sanding. What are my options for dealing with this? should I apply more mud and feather it out further or try to remove it and do it again?

Comment: More mud, make it smooth as possible, and minimize sanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sanding the paper tape, you definitely need more mud. So put on more mud.

Removing it would not really help, it would just make more of a mess you have to mud over.

I suggest 3-4", 6-8" and 12" for a progression in drywall "knives" (a coat with the small one, knock off only the high points, a coat with the medium one, knock off only the high points, a coat with the big one, if there are significant divots when sanding after that (there should not be), stop and recoat to fill the divots.